# Can I ask for a credit card upgrade within 6 months?

Tags: credit-card, india

This is my first credit card, and it is just 2 statements(months) old, both paid in full before due date.

I get invited to tech conferences frequently, so I do international flight bookings almost every month or two. However, as I get reimbursed the money at the conference, I'm good.

So, due to that and my international usage, my credit usage was pretty high for both the bill cycles [45% and 52%].

I think I would benefit better from a card with better points conversion. My current card is HDFC' Regalia First. I want to ask for a HDFC Regalia.
Is it a good idea to ask them now? Or should I wait for 6 months?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much difference between the 2 cards. It would be easier if you request for increase in credit limit.

Answer (score 1):

The search term you want is "product change", and it differs by card issuer.  Some won't do it at all, some make you wait a while.  Two months is probably too early, but before you wait for another 4 months, you might call the issuer and see what they say.  It won't hurt anything to find out their policy.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to India but in the US, 6 months is a good rule of thumb to wait until asking for an increased limit.